# Modularizing Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modularity

I am starting a new Angular project and trying to modularize all of my code – I'm tired of having massive app.js files and, because I'm developing a platform for a company, it's important my code is neat and modularized for easy testing, cleanliness, and ease of transition to Angular 2.

Currently, I have three angular files setting everything up:

Angular.module.js

```
angular
 .module('app', [
   /* Shared Modules */
   'app.config',
   'app.states'
   /* Feature Areas */
 ])
```

Angular.config.js

```
   angular
    .module('app', [
     /* Angular Modules */
     'ngResource',
     'ngSanitize',
     /* 3rd-party Modules */
     'ui.router'
    ]);
```

Angular.states.js

```
    angular
     .module('app')
     .config([
      '$stateProvider',
      '$urlRouterProvider',
      '$locationProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

       // Unknown URLs go to 404
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
       // No route goes to index
       $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

       // State provider for routing
      $stateProvider
       .state('home', {
         url: '/',
         views: {
          '': {
          templateUrl: 'home/_home.html'
          }
         }
      });
   }]);
```

This is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/stylesheets/screen.css">

      <!-- Angular Dependencies -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Angular Modules -->
      <script src="/app/app.config.js"></script>
      <script src="/app/app.states.js"></script>
      <script src="/app/app.module.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
     <div id="wrapper">
      <div ui-view></div>
     </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I keep hitting this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

What am I doing wrong? I'm having a hard time understanding how I get my various Angular files to interact with each other. I left out a controller of my state because I'm just testing the view right now.

Comment: The `angular.module("name", [])` syntax creates a module. You are doing this multiple times with the same module name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By writing :

```
angular.module('app', [
    /* Shared Modules */
    'app.config',
    'app.states'
    /* Feature Areas */
])
```

You create a module named `app` which requires 2 modules : `app.config` and `app.states`. If one of these is missing or not valid, the `app` module can't start.

In your `config.js`, you write `angular.module('app', [...])`. This will create a module named `app` with dependencies between the '[...]'. However, you've already created a module named 'app' in your `module.js`.

Change the module name, in `config.js` to `angular.module('app.config', [...])`.

In your `states.js` file, there is another thing:
`angular.module('app')` gives you the module you've created in your `module.js` file. You can call the config method on it, this is not a problem. However, you define, in your `app` module a dependecy to `app.states`. You can remove this dependency, or replace `angular.module('app')` by `angular.module('app.states', []).config(...)`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Makes so much sense. I had no idea how dependencies or injection really worked, I'm on a much better path now. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to correctly name your modules, the file name itself doesn't change anything :
Angular.module.js

```
angular
 .module('app', [
   /* Shared Modules */
   'app.config',
   'app.states'
   /* Feature Areas */
 ])
```

Angular.config.js

```
angular
    .module('app.config', [
     /* Angular Modules */
     'ngResource',
     'ngSanitize',
     /* 3rd-party Modules */
     'ui.router'
    ]);
```

Angular.states.js

```
angular
 .module('app.states')
 .config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Shortly

**Angular.config.js** redefines 'app' module and changes its dependencies.
So I'd like to suggest the following resolving...

### Angular.module.js

Make **Angular.module.js** (which is actually **app/app.module.js**) code to be the following:

```
angular
  .module('app', [
    /* Angular Modules */
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    /* 3rd-party Modules */
    'ui.router'
  ]);
```

### Angular.config.js

Make **Angular.config.js** (which is actually **app/app.config.js**) code to be:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      ...
    }
  ]);
```

### Angular.states.js

**Angular.states.js** (which is actually **app/app.states.js**) should be removed or just renamed to **app/app.config.js** (see above).

### index.html

**index.html** code should have the following order of files:

```
  <!-- Angular Modules -->
  <script src="/app/app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/app.config.js"></script>
```

### Other files

- Define module in separate file. For example, in **something.module.js**
- Module config code in **something.config.js** file
- etc

and include these files in **index.html** in the following order:

```
  <!-- Angular Modules -->
  <script src="/something/something.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/something/something.config.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/app.config.js"></script>
```

## In general

The following documentation about AngularJS code style could be helpful for you in the future for writing AngularJS modules: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md